# Kafka - Retention - Removes all offsets - windows - 0.9.X

Tags: apache-kafka

Kafka - Retention - Removes all offsets - windows - 0.9.X

When Kafka Retention happens for configured hours, it Removes all offsets and new customer able to get only messages that are created after the Log Cleaner/Retention Time.
Instead of cleaning the Records older than Retention Hour, it marks all messages in all Topic as Deleted and makes the Kafka Topic as no messages.

We set the log retention hour as 4  in the server.properties.

```
log.retention.hours=4
```

Is there a way to keep the messages for last 4 hours data ?